# Simple use of WebClient on Windows Phone 7 throws a NetworkError

Tags: c#, download, windows-phone-7

This code works in a WPF app but throws a NetworkException ("server not found") in WP7.  Why the difference?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadStringCompleted);
Uri token = new Uri("http://www.bing.com");

client.DownloadStringAsync(token);
```

Update: It looks like running Fiddler while debugging WP7 was the cause.  Fiddler also breaks the browser on the emulator.  Will post if I find a workaround for using Fiddler to debug the emulator.

Comment: Does `bing.com` work in a browser?

Comment: As of 2013 I'm still on that kind of problem when using APIs. I feel it has something to do with cross domain requests. Need to find a way to add a X-Target-URI header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed it works here. Can post code if you want a sample to try.

Might be an idea to check the proxy support doco if you're having trouble communicating out of the network from the emulator.

[Proxy Support for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351(v=VS.92).aspx)

Comment: It was broken yesterday but magically works today!  Thanks for trying out the code.