# How do I read a public twitter feed using .Net (on Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, twitter

I'm trying to read the public twitter status of a user so I can display it in my Windows Phone application.

I'm using Scott Gu's example: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx

When my code comes back from the async call, I get a "System.Security.SecurityException" as soon as I try to use the e.Result.

I know my uri is correct because I can plop it in the browser and get good results.

Here is my relavent code:

```
    public void LoadNewsLine()
    {
        WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

        twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
        twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=krashlander"));          
    }

    void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result); //exception thrown here!

        var message = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                      select tweet.Element("text").Value;

       //Set message and tell UI to update.
       //NewsLine = message.ToString(); 
       //RaisePropertyChanged("NewsLine");
    }
```

Any ideas anyone?

*SOLUTION:
I finally figured this one out.  I had simply forgotten to uncomment the: 
 capability in the WMAppManifest.xml.
Once I did that the security exception went away.*

Comment: Doesn't twitter have a throttle for number of times you can using their endpoints per hour/day? Perhaps you've maxed out? Also, you could try fiddler, see if you can capture the raw request. PS, your code worked for me.

Comment: I should not have reached any limit yet. Haven't called it more than a handful of times.

Comment: I also et same error..But can't find <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/> in my WIn 7 ( sl 4 ) applicatin...
anyhelp ??How to fix this one ???
I also tried same code on normal silverlight 4 application...It raise security exception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this one out. I had simply forgotten to uncomment the:

```
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
```

capability in the WMAppManifest.xml. Once I did that the security exception went away.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out TweetSharp. It's working quite well for me. 
http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'd prefer to do this without any 3rd party code. I simply want to READ the public status of a user I own (krashlander)  Would prefer to avoid any Authorization if possible.

Comment: Tweetsharp has moved to github and nuget, but the latest version doesn't support WP yet. http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TweetSharp also tweetsharp.com is no longer available. project looks defunct.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much dead. I chatted with the main developer Crena (?) a while ago. A real pity. He's still open to contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I hit something similar on my own app. This was my solution:

```
WebClient twitter=new WebClient();
twitter.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(twitter_OpenReadCompleted);
twitter.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com..."));
```

and

```
void twitter_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Still get the error.  Judging by comments above, might be a issue with the windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried code you posted and no exception was thrown, getting results as expected, all seems to be just fine. So there must be something on your pc, net connection (proxy etc) which is causing this. What is detailed exception, StackTrace? Maybe [Simple use of WebClient on Windows Phone 7 throws a NetworkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295929/simple-use-of-webclient-on-windows-phone-7-throws-a-networkerror) will help you?

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when cross referencing threads in any way. In this case it is probably related to Webclient always returning on the UI thread. You can probably solve the problem by using HttpWebRequest instead (which is better performance wise anyway).
Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8) thread on msdn forums for more info

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the application provided here .This application show you tweets for a specified username and also allows you to export tweets to pdf,excel,word,image etc ..

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/05/activereporting-with-twitter.html