# Simple Twitter library for Windows Phone to read public feeds

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

i'm looking for a simple Twitter library to read public twitter feeds and display them in my windows phone app.

A similar question was asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575693/how-do-i-read-a-public-twitter-feed-using-net-on-windows-phone) and one of the answers points to tweetsharp but this doesn't seem to be (well) maintained and available for windows phone 7.

any other libraries (for wp7) out there that you can recommend ?

Comment: I downloaded the source code of TweetSharp and compiled it. Hopefully TweetSharp will be available for Windows Phone (Mango) shortly through Nuget.

Comment: Good news, the owner of the TweetSharp library just made TweetSharp available for Mango through NuGet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweetsharp should work just fine? Read [this blog post by Tau Sick](http://clr-namespace.com/post/Using-TweetSharp-in-a-Windows-Phone-7-app.aspx) for details on how.

The source is now on [github/danielcrenna/tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) and the latest update was less than two months ago.

Comment: tweetsharp is no longer hosted on codeplex and the version available through nuget is not for the windows phone framework. Tau Sick mentions the version hosted on codeplex.

Comment: it seems that it's now hosted here: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp I will download it and try to compile it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just use WebClient to connect to the following kind of feed

`http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/user_id_no.rss`

Then use linq to read the data into an observable collection that you can bind to.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm hoping/looking for a library that has some basic support so i can easily add additional functionality in the future and don't have to do create the basics.